# htaccess mod_rewrite not working on another computer

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, frameworks

So I have an .htaccess file in a framework I am currently working on and it works on one computer but not on another. Both systems are windows 7 based and both are running WAMP Server 2.0. Not sure what this issue could be, but if anyone can lend a hand that'd be great.

`RewriteEngine on

        RewriteBase /home/

        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

        RewriteRule ^(.+) index.php/$1 [L]`

Comment: Does it not work at all or is it just this single rule/configuration?

Comment: It throws a 404 error when I omit the index.php from the URL. So I think it may not be doing the mod_rewrite. Not sure though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you checked that the line:

```
LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so
```

is uncommented in your Apache httpd.conf file on the second server?

Comment: I haven't, oops :-/ I will check when I get back home. If that's all it is I will shout for joy! :)

Answer (score 1):

I recall `mod_rewrite` must be enabled manually in WAMP. Make sure it is (a `phpinfo()` would tell you).

Comment: Ok I haven't checked there yet. Will do that when I get access tonight and let you know. Thanks!